# Django - URL problem for user profile view and edit profile view

Tags: django

In my Django project, specifically in my `accounts` app, I have 2 simple views, one allows users to view their profile (or other users' profiles), and the other one allows users to edit their own profile.

My `account.urls` looks like this

```
from django.urls import path
from accounts.views import ProfileView, EditProfileView

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:username>/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('edit/', EditProfileView.as_view(), name='edit'),
]
```

Everything works great, but if an user creates an accounts with the word `edit` as their username, they will NEVER be able to edit their profile, since the first URL pattern will always be matched.

What's the best way of solving this problem in Django?

I know I could change my URLs to something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:username>/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('<slug:username>/edit/', EditProfileView.as_view(), name='edit'),
]
```

But I prefer to NOT edit my URLs. I was wondering if there is another solution I don't know.

Comment: As per my knowledge you need to go with the second way getting the slug field cause you are trying to edit the profile and the form needs to be filled with the previous data. So, for that slug or id is required to know which user profile is being edited.

Comment: One simple solution is not allowing users to take this username. You can check in your view if username is "edit".